# (Follow-up) Cauchy product of more than two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Generalizations):
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{k_i = 0}^\infty a_{i,k_i} \right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\sum_{k_1 = 0}^n \sum_{k_2 = 0}^{k_1} \cdots \sum_{k_m = 0}^{k_{m-1}} a_{1, k_m} a_{2, k_{m-1} - k_m} \cdots a_{m, k_1 - k_2}}_{=S_n}
\end{equation}
I find it difficult to wrap my head around the expression on the right. Can $S_n$ be rewritten in a more suggestive way? For example, does the equality
\begin{equation}
\forall n:S_n=\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m\leq n}a_{1, k_1}\cdots a_{m, k_m}
\end{equation}
hold? Of course this different from asking if
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m\leq n}a_{1, k_1}\cdots a_{m, k_m}
\end{equation}
which was [my initial question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3734001/572841).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to point out the abuse of notation. The letter $n$ is overloaded, since it's both the number of series and the index that tends to infinity. I'll use $m$ as the number of series.

If you carefully check the blue indices in the sum
$$S_n=\sum_{k_1 = 0}^n \sum_{k_2 = 0}^{k_1} \cdots \sum_{k_m = 0}^{k_{m-1}} a_{1, \color{blue}{k_m}} a_{2, \color{blue}{k_{m-1} - k_m}} \cdots a_{m, \color{blue}{k_1 - k_2}}$$
you'll check that their sum is $k_1$, which is from $0$ to $n$. Therefore
$$S_n=\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m\leq n}a_{1, k_1}\cdots a_{m, k_m}.
$$
This form of writing this sum is propper as long as we know that we consider only integer *nonnegative* indices.

We can write it another way, which is closer to the idea that the Cauchy product of series is also a series. Namely,
$$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n\text{ where } c_n=\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m = n}a_{1, k_1}\cdots a_{m, k_m}.$$

To remember this idea I like thinking of multiplying the polynomials / power series. If we have the product
$$\prod_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{k_i = 0}^\infty a_{i,k_i}x^{k_i}\right)$$ then multiplying them formally we get the power series $\sum c_nx^n$ where $c_n$ is a sum of products of all coefficients $a_{i,k_i}$ such that their indices $k_i$ add up to $n$.

Comment: For a complete proof, we would have to show that for each $n$ the sets$$A_n:=\{(k_m,k_{m-1}-k_m,\ldots,k_1-k_2):0\leq k_n\leq\ldots\leq k_1\leq n\}$$and$$B_n:=\{(k_1,\ldots,k_m):k_1+\ldots+k_m\leq n\}$$are equal (i.e. $A_n\subset B_n$ **and** $B_n\subset A_n$) and you have shown that $A_n\subset B_n$, right?

Comment: I dont expect you to complete the proof, I just want to make sure that I understand.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Now, having $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ such that $k_1+\ldots+k_m\leq n$ you can find such $0\leq t_n\leq\ldots\leq t_m$ such that $k_1=t_m$, $k_2=t_{m-1}-t_m$ and so on and $k_m=t_1-t_2$.